# Find the 325th term of the series 7,16,25,34...

Tags: sequences-and-series

One of my friend gave me the series 7,16,25,34,43... I figured it out easily that the sum of digits is 7 in each case. How can I find the 325th term of this series? Also is there any trick/formula to get answer easily for these types of questions where sum of digits are integral constant ?

Comment: Your characterisation can't be right $-$ where do you go after $70$?

Comment: So is it homework, or did one of your friends ask you this question?

Comment: @tonyk  If OP's characterization is correct, then after 70, one would have 106.

Comment: @MJD: Perhaps. Then the question has a little meat to it at least!

Comment: @TonyK A question worth thinking about perhaps!  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870952/numbers-whose-digits-sum-to-7

Comment: Thanks for making a new and a clear topic for this

Answer (score 1):

Difference between consecutive terms is 9. Hence the following
$$7+9\cdot324=2923$$

Answer (score 1):

for your aritmethic sequence $$a_1=7,d=9=16-7=25-16=...$$ general term is $$a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$$ and 
in case $$n=325$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that $$16-7=25-16=34-25=43-34=9$$