# Numbers whose digits sum to 7

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, decimal-expansion

Let $S$ be the sequence of all positive integers whose decimal digits add to exactly 7, in increasing order:

$$S = \langle7, 16, 25, \ldots, 70, 106, 115, 124, \ldots 160, 205, \ldots, 10230010, \ldots\rangle$$

What is an efficient algorithm for finding the $n$th element of this sequence for a given positive integer $n$?

Comment: Hint: Binary search.

Comment: For $n \le 1000$ look at the $n$th row of http://oeis.org/A052221/b052221.txt

Comment: @j.j. I don't see how binary search is going to help either.  Suppose I ask you for $S(100)$.  What do you search for?

Comment: @MJD Let $N(k)$ be the number of elements of $S$ not exceeding $k$. That can be computed more or less efficiently. Now make a not too bad initial guess overestimating $S(n)$, and binary search from that initial guess.

Comment: @MJD: I find $n$ such that there are exactly $100$ such integers in the sequence below $n$, including $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by doing a binary search on the number of elements in the sequence below some number $M$.

To count how many numbers there are $\le M$ we must find a way to construct the numbers. The idea is the following: Go through each prefix of $M$, and assume that the next digit is less than the corresponding digit of $M$. Then the remaining digits $d_k,\dots,d_n$ can be set freely with a constraint of the form $d_k + \dots + d_n = l$, where $l$ is what is left of $7$ after subtracting the first digits. This is a standard counting problem.

Comment: I think I see your point now.  Thanks.

Comment: It's not quite as standard as you think - it's an _ordered_ permutation, which is a fairly unusual way of counting.  (1+1+2+3 is different from 1+2+3+1, but not from 1b+1a+2+3)  They're easy enough to enumerate by hand for a small case like this, but AFAIK they're not particularly well-studied.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: It should be just the usual ${n + l - 1 \choose l - 1}$.

Comment: @J.J. Ahhh, I see, you're just 'stars-and-bars'ing it.  I need to mentally double-check, but that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

A good point to start is to quickly determine the number of such numbers below certain "mielstone" limits.
Using the usual stars and bars argument, there are $m+7\choose 7$ such numbers below $10^m$. 
And more generally, if $a$ is any number with digitsum $ s\le 7$, then there are $m+7-s\choose 7-s$ such numbers $x$ with $a\cdot 10^m\le x<(a+1)\cdot 10^m$. These facts allow you to find rather quickly suitable estimates that converge to the desired result.

Comment: This is the right approach, though there are ${12 \choose 7}=792$ examples below $10^6$ so you may to adjust your expression slightly

Answer (score 0):

**Observation**: after $7,000,000$, all subsequent numbers from this list will be formed by sequentially inserting $0$'s into the $7$ digit numbers in the list (since after $1,111,111$, there can be no "new" combinations). As such, if we can formulate the sequence up to $7,000,000$, we'll be done in general.

**Aim**: to efficiently calculate the sequence up to $7,000,000$, at which point all future terms depend on previous terms. In doing so, generate a list of all 7 digit combinations, which will become the "base" for all further terms.

**The method:**

1. Take the multiples of $7$ in base $10$.
2. Translate these into base $8$. This will give you every number which, when viewed in base $10$, has digits which sum to 7 in order, plus some extras, whose digits sum to multiples of 7.
3. Manually remove these extras up to $7,000,000$ (still thinking of a better way, but this isn't so inefficient for this value).
4. Subsequent terms in the sequence are obtained by sequentially adding $0$'s to previous values.

---

Some more detail:

In base $10$, the trick for working out if a number is divisible by $9$ is if and only if the sum of the digits is a multiple of $9$. The proof for this is slightly enlightening:

$$a_na_{n-1}\ldots a_0 = \sum_{i=0}^na_i10^i\equiv \sum_{i=0}^na_i\mod9$$ as $10\equiv 1 \mod 9$. What's important here is that $10 = 9+1$. The same thing will work in base $8$ with multiples of $7$

---

When we translate the multiples of $7$ into base $8$, we get:

$$7\mapsto7\\14\mapsto16\\21\mapsto 25\\28\mapsto34\\35\mapsto43\\\vdots$$

**In base $8$ the multiples of $7$ are exactly the numbers whose digits sum to a multiple of $7$ in numerical order**. If we then interpret the numbers we get as if they were in base $10$, we will get an almost one-to-one correspondence with the base $10$ integers whose digit sum to $7$.

Now this will also include numbers whose digits sum to $14, 21, \ldots$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dense, but I don't see how this helps.

Comment: I don't see it either. Working in base $8$ when looking at a property of the decimal expansion doesn't sound convincing without further elaboration.

Comment: I've added some more detail. I hope that helps.

Comment: No, I still don't get it.

Comment: The idea is to reinterpret the base-10 numerals *as if* they were base-8 numerals, and doing so will put the elements of $S$  into (almost) one-to-one correspondence with the integers that are multiples of 7.  For example, $S$ contains $142$, which corresponds to $142_8 = 98 = 7\cdot14$. it's easy to count multiples of 7, so if it's not too hard to count how many base-8 numerals have a digit sum of 14, 21, 28, etc., then one could subtract those and get the right count for elements of $S$.

Comment: @MJD that's the idea. I'm currently trying to think of an efficient way of removing the extra digits.

Comment: This does not look much easier than taking decimal integers which are $2$ less than a multiple of $9$ and throwing away the wrong examples.  For large $n$, this will not be optimal in either route as you have to throw away too many examples.

Comment: @Henry. That's probably true I guess. Although we only need to do this up to $7,000,000$, after which the sequence will repeat with added $0$'s. But I do think that this is a more guided way of creating the initial part of the sequence than a binary search.

Comment: After $7,000,000$ you still get an increasing number of places to put the extra $0$s

Answer (score 0):

Let me try answering it a fun way...
base 10 will use 9x-2 to make a set like (7, 16, 24,...100000000006)
Now what numbers do we need to ignore? Those that sum greater than 7...now there's a trick to only get these numbers from the set above in programming....
when you hit a number that sums over 7 using the above series you take the number, find the last digit with a number in it, subtract 1 and move it to the end, and add 1 to the digit after...
So for 70 since 7 is the last digit we subtract 1 to make 6, move that to the end (06) and add a 1 to the digit after 7 (106) to get the next number in the series...
160 would jump to 205 (6-1=5, add 1 after)
250 will be 304
340 will be 403
430 will be 502
520 will be 601
610 will be 700
700 will be 1006
1,060 will be 1,105
...
10,600,000 will be 11,000,005

so you could do something like this...
input n
ans=7
n=n-1
do until n=0
   Ans=Ans+9
   If sum(eachnuminans)>7
       Ans=Ans-9
       Pos=Find(first nonzero location)
       X=ans(pos)
       Ans(pos)=0
       Ans(pos+1)=ans(pos+1)+1
       Ans(1)=X-1
   Loop
   n=n-1
Loop